# Magento 2.3.6: Order email is sending but Customer Account create/forgot password email not sending?

Tags: magento2, magento2-3-3, magento2-3, magento231, magento234

We have checked order email is sending proper,when we tried to create new customer or forgot password that time email is not getting. when we have checked in exception.log file we have got the below error.

```
main.CRITICAL: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php:103, Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:304)"} []
```

Thank's in Advance,

Comment: Did you set store email addresses properly ? They are used to as sender email address and default value is hello@example.com. If you are using a SMTP module, it tries to send as hello@example.com your smtp provider doesn't allow to use that email.

Comment: yes,store email addressed properly

Comment: Do you use any custom SMTP extension ?

Comment: @MehmetUygur No,we have not installed any custom SMTP exension